What is the best alternative to dialysis?
What is the best alternative to dialysis?  I want to "design" at a purely theoretical level an industrial installation for the purification of a recombinant protein and dialysis is not suitable on an industrial scale from what I have read.  I was thinking maybe an ion exchange chromatographic column with cationite to remove the imidazole or maybe a desalting column. Do you think the desalting column would be a good idea?  How would the actual process go?

In my particular case, the protein is at a pH below the isoelectric point and I would not want to make a pH change that would allow my protein to not bind to the ion exchange column

Dialysis is usually used to exchange solvents, not to generate the final pure protein (a column is typically required for that). There are usually reasons to exchange solvent, including incompatibility of the original solvent and the column.

@BuckThorn Thanks for the reply.  I was also thinking about a concentration after the stage that would replace dialysis.  The goal of dialysis in my case was to remove the imidazole from the protein solution, and at the industrial level, dialysis is not recommended.
